# Where do you store arbitrary home page data?

Tags: 7

There's some welcome heading, text, video that goes on the front page. Currently this is stored in variables but it feels wrong to me because, well, it's a wall of text and variables is loaded on every page. Any module helping here?

Comment: What happened to the avatar?  Had to double check that someone wasn't impersonating you.

Comment: It was loading from Gravatar I think which I now consider a privacy violation and removed myself. Fixed. Also, impersonating with 3K points and a golden badge? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use two different solutions, depending on the situation.

The easiest is to make a custom content type and field it out the way you want.  Make a node, and assign it at the home page.  If this is your own site, then you can trust yourself to only use it once.  If this is for someone else, you either have to trust them, or put some mechanism in place so that they can't reuse this content type elsewhere.  Modules like [Viewfield](https://drupal.org/project/viewfield), especially combined with Nodequeues can be used to lists of things.  The custom content type concept can also be extended to a custom entity type if you are inclined to do so.

The second way is to make a custom [Panel](https://drupal.org/project/panels) page, and then assign it to the home page.  You get total flexability here to do just about anything you need.  Text can be handled by the custom content pages.  Other things, like media, are either handled by custom blocks / custom content pages, or internal-use content types that you [Rabbit Hole](https://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) and exclude from search results with [Custom Search](https://drupal.org/project/custom_search).  Lists of things can just be handled with normal view content panes.

Of the two, we have been using the custom content type more than we have been using custom panel pages.

Answer (score 0):

If its all editable why not creating a content type "homepage"?
There will be only 1 node of this type(so what...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom settings form, the benefits:

1. Easy to build (Using the form API, hook_menu, hook_permission)
2. Easy to maintenance (content)- When you need to edit some content you may go to the settings form page and just edit whatever you need.
3. Easy to maintenance and add new features (code) - You can always add a new field (Image, text, embed and so on by using the great [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) .

In my opinion this is the best solution for this kind of need, using homepage content type is an overkill..

Thanks.

Comment: Oh thanks for praising the Form API, I wrote significant chunks of it :)

Comment: Then it's the worst API I ever saw.. :D